# Access an excel workbook through PHP + PDO

Tags: php, excel, pdo

Is it at all possible to connect to an Excel workbook through PHP + PDO?

I'm trying to get data out of both Access and Excel at the same time, and PDO has yet to fail me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Windows, have the MS Jet engine (or Access/Excel ODBC drivers) installed and use the PDO ODBC driver, then you should be able to query both Access databases and properly structured Excel spreadsheets.

Comment: Cheers winvds, I'll try that in a bit